# Delete attributes for validation with javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I am creating a function to add a `regex` on an input  postal code.
the regex I add him only for some nations, for example France.

The function that I have done I call it back when I select the nation through a select, 
and this works when I add the attributes to the input, 
instead it doesn't work,
if later I want to change nation selecting a nation for which I must not check the postal code.

> The browser continues to effect the validation to return me the error
>   of validation 'Le champ doit contenir 5 chiffres.'

How can I modify the javascript to annul well the attributes added ?

Thanks

```js
function CodePostalRegEx(input, action) {
  if (action == "add") {
    $(input).attr('data-val', 'true'); // turn on validation
    $(input).attr('data-val-regex', 'Le champ doit contenir 5 chiffres'); // message to show when validation fails
    $(input).attr('data-val-regex-pattern', "^(([0-8][0-9])|(9[0-5]))[0-9]{3}$"); //regex
  } else {
    $(input).attr('data-val', 'false');
    $(input).removeAttr('data-val-regex'); // message to show when validation fails
    $(input).removeAttr('data-val-regex-pattern'); //regex
    $(input).removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
    $(input).removeData('validator');
  }
  $("#MonProfilForm").each(function() {
    $.data($(this)[0], 'validator', false);
  });
  $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#MonProfilForm");
}



 $(".Identite #PaysNaissance").change(function () {

    if ($(".Identite #PaysNaissance").val().toLowerCase() != "france") {

        CodePostalRegEx(".Identite #CodePostalNaissance", "remove");

        $(".Identite #CodePostalNaissance").unmask("data-mask");

        if ($(".Identite #CommuneNaissance").hasClass('ui-autocomplete-input'))
        {
            $(".Identite #CommuneNaissance").autocomplete("destroy");
            $(".Identite #CommuneNaissance").removeData('autocomplete');
        }
       

        if ($(".Identite #CodePostalNaissance").hasClass('ui-autocomplete-input')) {
            $(".Identite #CodePostalNaissance").autocomplete("destroy");
            $(".Identite #CodePostalNaissance").removeData('autocomplete');
        }

     

        
    }
    else {
       
        $(".Identite #CodePostalNaissance").mask("00000");
        CodePostalRegEx(".Identite #CodePostalNaissance", "add");
        setupAC()
        

    }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/Moi" class="" id="MonProfilForm" method="post" role="form" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div class="form-group label-floating has-success-website">
    <label class="control-label" for="ClientModel_EtatCivil_PaysNaissance">Pays de naissance</label>
    <select class="form-control valid" for="pp8" id="PaysNaissance" name="ClientModel.EtatCivil.PaysNaissance" aria-invalid="false">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="EX-REP YOUGOSLAVE DE MACEDOINE">EX-REP YOUGOSLAVE DE MACEDOINE</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="FIDJI">FIDJI</option>
      <option value="FINLANDE">FINLANDE</option>
      <option value="FRANCE">FRANCE</option>
      <option value="GABON">GABON</option>
      <option value="GAMBIE">GAMBIE</option>
      <option value="GEORGIE">GEORGIE</option>
      <option value="GEORGIE DU SUD ET LES ILES SANDWICH DU SUD">GEORGIE DU SUD ET LES ILES SANDWICH DU SUD</option>
      <option value="GHANA">GHANA</option>
    </select>
    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger help-block" data-valmsg-for="ClientModel.EtatCivil.PaysNaissance" data-valmsg-replace="true" id="pp8"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group label-floating has-success-website">
        <label class="control-label" for="ClientModel_EtatCivil_CodePostalNaissance">Code postal de naissance</label>
        <input class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input valid" for="pp6" id="CodePostalNaissance" name="ClientModel.EtatCivil.CodePostalNaissance" type="text" value="3440" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false">
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger help-block" data-valmsg-for="ClientModel.EtatCivil.CodePostalNaissance" data-valmsg-replace="true" id="pp6"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7">
      <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
        <label class="control-label" for="ClientModel_EtatCivil_CommuneNaissance">Commune de naissance</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="CommuneNaissance2" name="ClientModel.EtatCivil.CommuneNaissance" type="text" value="" style="display: inline-block;">
        <input class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" id="CommuneNaissance" name="ClientModel.EtatCivil.CommuneNaissance" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" style="display: none;">
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger help-block" data-valmsg-for="ClientModel.EtatCivil.CommuneNaissance" data-valmsg-replace="true" id="pp7"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-container-detail-footer text-center content-container-detail-footer-fixed-bottom col-lg-12">
    <button class="flat-butt flat-primary-butt flat-butt-responsive" type="submit" name="action:Save">
        <span class="">Enregistrer</span>
       </button>
    <button class="flat-butt flat-primary-send flat-butt-responsive" type="submit" name="action:AskSend">
        <span class="visible-xs-inline">Envoyer</span>
        <span class="hidden-xs">Envoyer à mon notaire</span>
       </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: post also your html

Comment: @ewwink I have added a part of my form html

Comment: how the function `CodePostalRegEx()` called? please add it also in your question

Answer (score 0):

You have some selectors with class, then id.  You only need the id since it must be unique and it is the fastest selector.  I also modified to use a cache of the selected element thus making the code simpler and not hitting the DOM with a selector as much (not traversing)  I avoid an error by an empty missing function I added. `setupAC`
I also added this line: `jqinput.data('valRegexPattern', reg);`  Note the dash removed and camel case per the standard.

This code seems odd, did you mean to process the form or the inputs in the form?  Either way this seems wrong:

```
$("#MonProfilForm").each(function() {
    $.data($(this)[0], 'validator', false);
});
```

So, given that you need one or the other of these:

The form:

```
$("#MonProfilForm").data('validator', false);
```

The inputs

```
$("#MonProfilForm").find('input').each(function() {
    $.data($(this)[0], 'validator', false);
});
```

```js
function CodePostalRegEx(jqinput, action) {
  var reg = "^(([0-8][0-9])|(9[0-5]))[0-9]{3}$";
  if (action == "add") {
    jqinput.attr('data-val', 'true'); // turn on validation
    jqinput.attr('data-val-regex', 'Le champ doit contenir 5 chiffres'); // message to show when validation fails
    jqinput.attr('data-val-regex-pattern', reg); //regex
    jqinput.data('valRegexPattern', reg);
  } else {
    jqinput.attr('data-val', 'false');
    jqinput.removeAttr('data-val-regex'); // message to show when validation fails
    jqinput.removeAttr('data-val-regex-pattern'); //regex
    jqinput.removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
    jqinput.removeData('validator');
  }
  $("#MonProfilForm").each(function() {
    $.data($(this)[0], 'validator', false);
  });
  $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#MonProfilForm");
}

function setupAC() {}

$("#PaysNaissance").change(function() {
  var cpn = $("#CodePostalNaissance");
  var cn = $("#CommuneNaissance");
  if ($(this).val().toLowerCase() != "france") {
    CodePostalRegEx(cpn, "remove");
    cpn.unmask("data-mask");
    if (cn.hasClass('ui-autocomplete-input')) {
      cn.autocomplete("destroy");
      cn.removeData('autocomplete');
    }
    if (cpn.hasClass('ui-autocomplete-input')) {
      cpn.autocomplete("destroy");
      cpn.removeData('autocomplete');
    }
  } else {
    cpn.mask("00000");
    CodePostalRegEx(cpn, "add");
    setupAC();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.11/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<form action="/Moi" class="" id="MonProfilForm" method="post" role="form" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div class="form-group label-floating has-success-website">
    <label class="control-label" for="ClientModel_EtatCivil_PaysNaissance">Pays de naissance</label>
    <select class="form-control valid" for="pp8" id="PaysNaissance" name="ClientModel.EtatCivil.PaysNaissance" aria-invalid="false">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="EX-REP YOUGOSLAVE DE MACEDOINE">EX-REP YOUGOSLAVE DE MACEDOINE</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="FIDJI">FIDJI</option>
      <option value="FINLANDE">FINLANDE</option>
      <option value="FRANCE">FRANCE</option>
      <option value="GABON">GABON</option>
      <option value="GAMBIE">GAMBIE</option>
      <option value="GEORGIE">GEORGIE</option>
      <option value="GEORGIE DU SUD ET LES ILES SANDWICH DU SUD">GEORGIE DU SUD ET LES ILES SANDWICH DU SUD</option>
      <option value="GHANA">GHANA</option>
    </select>
    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger help-block" data-valmsg-for="ClientModel.EtatCivil.PaysNaissance" data-valmsg-replace="true" id="pp8"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group label-floating has-success-website">
        <label class="control-label" for="ClientModel_EtatCivil_CodePostalNaissance">Code postal de naissance</label>
        <input class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input valid" for="pp6" id="CodePostalNaissance" name="ClientModel.EtatCivil.CodePostalNaissance" type="text" value="3440" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false">
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger help-block" data-valmsg-for="ClientModel.EtatCivil.CodePostalNaissance" data-valmsg-replace="true" id="pp6"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7">
      <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
        <label class="control-label" for="ClientModel_EtatCivil_CommuneNaissance">Commune de naissance</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="CommuneNaissance2" name="ClientModel.EtatCivil.CommuneNaissance" type="text" value="" style="display: inline-block;">
        <input class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" id="CommuneNaissance" name="ClientModel.EtatCivil.CommuneNaissance" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" style="display: none;">
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger help-block" data-valmsg-for="ClientModel.EtatCivil.CommuneNaissance" data-valmsg-replace="true" id="pp7"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-container-detail-footer text-center content-container-detail-footer-fixed-bottom col-lg-12">
    <button class="flat-butt flat-primary-butt flat-butt-responsive" type="submit" name="action:Save">
        <span class="">Enregistrer</span>
       </button>
    <button class="flat-butt flat-primary-send flat-butt-responsive" type="submit" name="action:AskSend">
        <span class="visible-xs-inline">Envoyer</span>
        <span class="hidden-xs">Envoyer à mon notaire</span>
       </button>
  </div>
</form>
```